# Generating half of all permutations by never generating a permutation and its reverse?

Tags: algorithm, permutation, pseudocode

I am looking for an algorithm that computes only half of the possible permutations. For example elements a b c have the following permutations:

a b c

a c b

b a c

b c a

c a b

c b a

When a permutation is an opposite (in reverse order) of another permutation, they are considered to be the same. For example, (a b c) ~ (c b a). I need the algorithm to compute only half the permutations. In this case, that would be either (a b c) (a c b) (b a c) or (c b a) (b c a) (c a b). I suppose different sets of 3 are possible too, depending on the algorithm.

I have tried searching for this algorithm, all I have found language-specific algorithm using included function with permutation indexing. I need a general pseudo-code. I'm working with VB.NET

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way:

1. Use a double for-loop to fix the beginning and end of the permutation, with `index[end] > index[beginning]`;
2. Generate all the permutations for the leftover elements and put them in between.

E.g., for 4 elements:

```
a * * b -> a c d b, a d c b
a * * c -> a b d c, a c d b
a * * d -> a b c d, a c b d
b * * c -> b a d c, b d a c
b * * d -> b a c d, b c a d
c * * d -> c a b d, c b a d
```

Since the first and last element will never be the last and first elemnt of another permutation when generate the permutations this way, and you are producing exactly `n! / 2` permutations, it is guaranteed the you only get half of all the permutations.

Answer (score 1):

It is same as generating normal one it is just that first is lexicographically before last. So you put first on first place, then all lex greater on last and other in middle as usually.

This condition can be also used as filter to filter out unwanted if that makes simpler.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. I will post my pseudocode for this problem in case anyone else needs it in the future:

```
SET of size (n)
SUBSET of size (n-2)

for i=1 to n
    for j=i+1 to n
        create SUBSET = SET \ { SET[i] , SET[j] }
        do permutations loop, function for SUBSET
        {
          calculate a permutation P for SUBSET
          construct full permutation FP = SET[i] & P & SET[j]
          print or use FP
          continue permutations loop
        }
    next j
next i
```